# TypeError: The "options.agent" property must be one of Agent-like Object, undefined, or false. Received an instance of Object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, testing, msw

I am trying to write a simple test for logging in.

The error message:
`TypeError: The "options.agent" property must be one of Agent-like Object, undefined, or false. Received an instance of Object`

The test:

```
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query';
import SignIn from '../SignIn';
import { setupServer } from 'msw/node'
import { render, screen, fireEvent, waitFor, waitForElementToBeRemoved } from '@testing-library/react';
import { rest } from 'msw';

// set up server to mock API login requests
let server = setupServer();
beforeAll(() => server.listen())
// afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers())
afterAll(() => server.close())

const queryClient = new QueryClient();
const onSubmit = jest.fn();

beforeEach(() => {
    //onSubmit.mockClear();
    render(
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
            <SignIn onSuccess={onSubmit} />
        </QueryClientProvider>
    );
})

describe('SignIn Domain', () => {
    test('Successful login', async () => {

        server.use(
            rest.post('/api/Auth/Login', (req, res, ctx) => {
                return res(ctx.json([{ token: 'myToken' }]));
            }),
        );

        await waitFor(() => {
            fireEvent.change(getEmail(), {
                target: {
                    value: "myemail@gmail.com"
                }
            })
        });

        // click the button
        await waitFor(() => {
            fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('Continue'));
        });
           
        await waitForElementToBeRemoved(screen.getByText('Processing...'));
    )}
)}
```

Test test steps should be as follows:
- Enter email
- Click Next (This will grey out and a Spinner will appear while it loads)
- Re-render page to display password entry
- Enter password
- Click Sign In

I have looked deeply but can't find a resolution to the error that I am getting. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "airdrop-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fluentui/react": "^8.104.5",
    "@fluentui/react-icons": "^1.1.145",
    "@fluentui/react-icons-mdl2": "^1.3.29",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/d3": "^6.7.5",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/filesaver": "^0.0.30",
    "@types/geojson": "^7946.0.10",
    "@types/mapbox-gl": "^2.7.10",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.55",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.52",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.18",
    "@types/react-motion": "0.0.29",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "d3": "^6.7.0",
    "d3-hexbin": "^0.2.2",
    "d3-svg-legend": "^2.25.6",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "fluent": "^0.13.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "mapbox-gl": "^2.12.0",
    "msw": "^0.28.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-cookie": "^4.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-map-gl": "^6.1.21",
    "react-motion": "^0.5.2",
    "react-query": "^3.39.2",
    "react-rnd": "^10.4.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.4",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "sprintf-js": "^1.1.2",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/d3-hexbin": "^0.2.3",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.12",
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.6",
    "@types/sprintf-js": "^1.1.2",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-15": "^1.4.4",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.7",
    "jest": "^29.3.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.3.1",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.3",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.6.2"
  }
}
```